# What books do you use to study general jurisprudence in US?

Tags: united-states, jurisprudence

I'm a russian law student. I want to have a look on your ways of studying general jurisprudence. I mean the discipline, that includes topics on what law, rights and state are, their genesis, laws of their functioning, the stracture of law, norms etc, etc. In Russia this discipline is called The theory of state and law. Also we have the discipline, that is called jurisprudence, that contains sort of same knowledge. Textbooks are called respectevily.

What books do you use to study these topics?

Comment: This subject is not regularly studied by law students or by non-law students taking a law course (e.g. criminal justice or business law or political science) in a course with that scope in the United States. A small minority of 2L or 3L law students might take such a course as an elective but systemic study of general jurisprudence as as subject is the exception and not the norm in the United States. More often, those issues are sprinkled in bits and pieces in other core curricular areas for law students. Arguably "Constitutional law" fills a similar place in terms of importance  in the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

I am in England but, if it is any help, I would suggest:

*Legal Philosophies* by J W Harris as an introductory text which gives references to other books.